# Python create dataframe from sql query result

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I have sql query with multiple temporary table creation and one final select statement.

Let's imagine query example:

```
select 
        t1.Variable11,
        t1.Variable12,
        t2.Variable13
    into #R1
    from t1
    join t2
    on t1.Key1= t2.key1 and t1.Key2= t2.key2
    where t1.Variable1 > 100

select 
        t3.Variable21,
        t3.Variable22,
        t4.Variable23
    into #R2
    from t3
    join t4
    on t3.Key1= t4.key1 and t3.Key2= t4.key2
    where t3.Variable1 > 200


select 
        #R1.*,
        #R2.*
    from #R1
    join #R2
    on #R1.Variable11= #R2.Variable21
```

I connect to sql server with pyodbc connector:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', server=server_name,
                            database=db_name, trusted_connection='yes', MARS_Connection='yes')
```

I do not want to re-write code. 
I just want to write function which will return pandas dataframe.
When i try to use `pandas.read_sql()` function i receive error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

When i try to use `pyodbs.execute()` i receive error:

> No results. Previous SQL was not a query.

how to handle a sql script with multiple temporary tables creation and one final select statements?

Comment: Your final select uses `R1` and `R2` and you are selecting into `#R1` and `#R2`.

Comment: Use temp table for `R1` and `R2`

Comment: Yes, I should have written #R1 and #R2 in the examples. But this is not the question here. I do not have this problem in real example.

Comment: Put `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your script block and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://python:python@Database/Tablename?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')
connection = engine.connect()
SQL='select * from ' + Tablename
Tfrom_sql=pd.read_sql(SQL, connection)
connection.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).